# Error when importing schema.sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I'm new to sql, currently I am using phpMyAdmin via XAMP, I think that uses mysql so correct me if I'm wrong by saying that.  Anywhos, I'm trying to import a schema.sql data file into my database I created called "test" but I got an error upon importing it:

It says

> Import has been successfully finished, 1 queries executed.
>   (schema.sql)

But then it also gives me an error message:

```
CREATE TABLE `population` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `location` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> ## 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

and :

> Notice in .\import.php#704  Undefined variable: import_text Backtrace

I'm not sure what the issue is.  The database I created is completely and has nothing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `id` is the auto-column in question; auto-columns need to be defined as a key, for example as a unique key or a primary key. In your case, a primary key is a good idea because - well, it's your id-column.

```
CREATE TABLE `population` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `location` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually fixed it by using KEY (id) but I see what you mean by having it as primary key.